# Can you change the VPN you are using through php program

Tags: php, vpn

I have what I am hoping is a basic question, since I really know very little about VPNs it probably isn't..

I have a multitude of VMs and they are split on 2 VPNs.. is there some way when I'm doing something that effects all VMs such as changing a MYSQL table structure that I can switch from 1 vpn to the other within the PHP program making the change.  I am not able to mess with the VPNs or the servers involved so it would have to be a totally programmatic answer.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I mean its possible but, php doesn't have access to your network system.
You need something like Python or C or C++

> I'm doing something that effects all VMs such as changing a MYSQL table structure that I can switch from 1 vpn to the other within the PHP program making the change.

It kind of sound likes you want to change different database connections. Can you elaborate more on what you want? Why are you using two different vpns?

Why don't you have to different tables or databases and have one program use database#1 and the other